# HERE Historical Traffic Flow Data

Tags: xmlhttprequest, here-api, here-traffic

How to get historical traffic flow data via http request? I know that HERE provide real time traffic flow data but I need historical data for forecasting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Historical data is not available through a REST API on the developer portal.